# Increment Counter in a while loop after X seconds

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run a script which takes input from text file and based on the number of entries in it, a command is executed as many number of times. 
Below is an overview:

```
cat /tmp/file.txt | while read name
do
<<execute a command using value of $name>>
done
```

What is happening is sometimes the command executed for particular $name is getting hung due to known issues. Therefore I need in such cases that the command on every value of $name runs only for X number of seconds and if it is not able to complete within that stipulated time, terminate the process and increment loop counter. 
I was able to make use of sleep and kill but it is terminated the entire loop. I want the next values to be processed in case command gets hung on a row/value.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want something like `timeout`.

```
timeout 4 <command>
```

Comment: I don't have "timeout" utility on my server. Nor I can install it.